# How to use update Resource Controllers laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-4, controllers

I have Customer Controller with index, edit, update methods

```
Route::resource('customer', 'CustomerController');
```

Controller methods update

```
public function update($id) { echo $id; }
```

my HTML Form

```
<form action="/customer/1" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="" />
</form>
```

I have following a Documentation here
http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers
PUT/PATCH /resource/{id}    update

It's seems not working for me, how to use it? thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To use the `PATH`, `PUT` or `DELETE` HTML methods you need to add a hidden input with `_method`. Like the following...

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [Form Builder](https://github.com/illuminate/html/blob/master/FormBuilder.php). Example using blade:

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE')) }}
```

That will automatically add this for you

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in Laravel 4:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => URL::to('customer/1'), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Laravel resource controller. For update a page, I copied it from insert page after then

Just I added an extra field to update view like as

```
            {{ method_field('put') }}
```

Just use this as for update

```
 <form method="post" action="{{ URL::to('customer',$customer['id'])}}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            {{ method_field('put') }}
```