# AngularJS POST and PUT not found

Tags: angularjs, post, laravel, put

Getting the list is not a problem but if I tried to Update or Add a record, it does not seem to work.

Here's the code:

```
angular.module('userApp.services',[])
.factory('User', function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost/api/v1/users/:id',
    {id:'@id'},
    {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
});
```

My RESTful service  is built in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

You are not injecting the `ngResource` module you need to use.

```
angular.module('userApp.services',['ngResource'])
.factory('User', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost/api/v1/users/:id', { id:'@id' }, {
      update: { method: 'PUT' }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: thanks but I tried it your way, still the same error. 

PUT http://localhost/api/v1/users/ 404 (Not Found)

Comment: There was some markup mistake in case you copied my code, try now cause I corrected it and give me please some feedback ;)

Comment: still the same though :( error 404 not found. my restful framework is laravel if that helps. it works on curl but i just can't manage to make it work with a form.

Comment: I don't now if it has something to do with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15214515/2834553) but try changing `method` to `_method`...

Comment: yeah tried that as well, not working. anyway, appreciate your help man.

Comment: Did you find the problem @DavidAlrdrin ?